# How to make shared storage/settings for Windows Universal app?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, windows-8.1, win-universal-app

i was trying to develop a universal app for Windows 8.1 in C# using Visual Studio 2015. for testing i saved some text in RoamingSettings in Windows project then while trying to read that text in Windows Phone Project the app crashes due to a "NullRefrenceException".. Here is my Code

in Windows Project :

```
Windows.Storage.ApplicationDataContainer RoamingSettings = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.RoamingSettings;

RoamingSettings.Values["USERNAME"] = userNameInput.Text;
```

in Windows Phone Project :

```
Windows.Storage.ApplicationDataContainer RoamingSettings = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.RoamingSettings;

myTextBlock.Text = RoamingSettings.Values["USERNAME"].ToString();
```

as i mentioned the Windows Phone app crashes in both the emulator and the physical phone, did i write the required code for this feature ? is the Roaming Settings/Folder is the place which stores universal apps data ?

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, for roaming settings to work, you need to be logged in on both devices with the same `Microsoft` account.

These settings are not instantly synced so you can't test them on your phone device immediately after you update the setting on your `Windows` device.

Also make sure you check whether the value you are trying to retrieve is not `null`:

```
if(RoamingSettings.Values.ContainsKey("USERNAME"))
{
    myTextBlock.Text = RoamingSettings.Values["USERNAME"].ToString();
}
```

After this you should not get any `NullReferenceException`, but when the value is synced sometime later, the code in the `if` block will eventually execute.

Comment: thank you very much , i've already logged in my pc and phone with the same Microsoft account but i tested it immediately after updating settings on my pc so it is a matter of time i guess...

thanks again for your time and concern